# PHP MYSQL script mistake

Tags: php, mysql

please help to find a a mistake: The result is the Query is empty! I do not where the problem might come, actually I know that something might be wrong mysql_querry:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT PEOPLE.ID AS ID, 
                            PEOPLE.NAME AS NAME, 
                            TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO, 
                            RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS TICKET_DATE, 
                            PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS MONEY, 
                            CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER, 
                            PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT
        FROM PEOPLE, RECEIPTS 
        INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID 
        INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
        INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
        WHERE TICKETS.PERSON = '.$ID.'");
if ($num > 0 ) {
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
        $ID = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"ID"));
        $ID = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"ID"));
        $NAME = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"NAME"));
        $TICKET_NO = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"TICKET_NO"));
        $TICKET_DATE = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"TICKET_DATE"));
        $MONEY = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"MONEY"));
        $CUSTOMER = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"CUSTOMER"));
        $PAYMENT = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"PAYMENT"));

    $row .= '<tr>
    <td><a href="update.php?ID='.$ID.'">'.$ID.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="update.php?NAME='.$NAME.'">'.$NAME.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="update.php?TICKET_NO='.$TICKET_NO.'">'.$TICKET_NO.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="update.php?TICKET_DATE='.$TICKET_DATE.'">'.$TICKET_DATE.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="update.php?MONEY='.$MONEY.'">'.$MONEY.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="update.php?CUSTOMER='.$CUSTOMER.'">'.$CUSTOMER.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="update.php?PAYMENT='.$PAYMENT.'">'.$PAYMENT.'</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?ID='.$ID.'">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>';

++$i; }} else { $row = '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Nothing found</td></tr>'; 
}

mysql_close();
?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0"><? echo $row ?></table>
```

I much appreciete your support!

Comment: You have no variable `$ID` defined prior to the query, so the query reads `TICKETS.PERSON = ''` with an empty string.

Comment: Be aware that you _should not_ be using `addslashes()/stripslashes()` and the mis-feature `magic_quotes_gpc` should be turned _off_. The proper way to escape with the `mysql_*()` API is `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: how you can directly write if ($num > 0 )? what is the value of $num?

Comment: try to execute the query in mysql console or phpmyadmin

Comment: thanks for suggestion: in PHPMYADMIN - the QUERY is fine with WHERE TICKETS.PERSON = PEOPLE.ID")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ID` value is empty you must assign value in it.

Secondly, you're checking `$num>0` where but what is the value of `$num`?

From my point of view your are trying to get the count of rows fetch.

Comment: ok,I modified WHERE TICKETS.PERSON = PEOPLE.ID");
But nothing changed

Comment: whats in $num? are you trying to check the count of fetch row? then use mysql_num_rows()

Comment: I use the the idea with other similar script and  $num>0 works fine... I wanted to repet the same scenario with other similar sript and I get EMTY QUERY - the problem might be in  logic of SQL

Comment: echo "SELECT PEOPLE.ID AS ID,PEOPLE.NAME AS NAME,        TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO, RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS TICKET_DATE,  PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS MONEY,CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER,          PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT FROM PEOPLE, RECEIPTS INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID WHERE TICKETS.PERSON = '.$ID.'"  //print this then use the result to check the query

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in G:\home\localhost\test.php

Comment: your using long query try to add things one by one or using this query on php console or any mysql interface by giving values